# allBundles is not logging custom bundles in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, bundle

Bundle which I created do not show up. The following code prints out only the Application Bundle, whereas I have added my custom bundle. But this does not Print out with the NSLog.

```
for (id obj in [NSBundle allBundles]) {
    NSLog(@"Bundle Data= %@",obj);
};
```

Only, thing which it outputs is ***ApplicationName***.bundle.

So, any ideas why is it not Logging out the added bundle

Added the new code, after realising that  bundle was not loaded.

```
 NSString *bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myBundle" ofType:@"bundle"];
 NSBundle *myBundle=[[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:bundlePath];
 [myBundle load];
 for (id obj in [NSBundle allBundles]) {
    NSLog(@"Bundle Data= %@",obj);
 };
```

This was now logging out the following lines:

```
2013-03-05 18:55:37.248 MyApp[414:c07] Bundle Data= NSBundle </Users/MyUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8DA9E19E-5028-4654-A0E0-251372B08139/MyApp.app> (loaded)
2013-03-05 18:55:37.250 MyApp[414:c07] Bundle Data= NSBundle </Users/MyUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8DA9E19E-5028-4654-A0E0-251372B08139/MyApp.app/myBundle.bundle> (not yet loaded)
```

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `allBundles` list bundles that are not loaded. You may want to use `Bundle(identifier: "your.bundle.url)`.

OP: use `allFrameworks` to list all frameworks, you may find something useful there too.